# RGB color system as a data type

Tags: c

> An RGB color system can represent 256 different colors by combining different shades of red, green and blue. Each shade can be represented as a number. Define a C type to represent the RGB state.

From my understanding this would be a proper C type, not sure if I am correct though:

```
struct{
    int R[256];
    int G[256];
    int B[256];
} color;
```

Would that be correct or is there a more proper / more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: No need for the `int`s in the struct to be arrays. Just simple `int` is enough (or `short`, or even `unsigned char`). Other than that, should be fine.

Comment: Note that the problem statement says it can represent 256 colors, not 256 colors per channel as many of the people posting here seem to be assuming.

Comment: A solution that complies with the stipulation might be: `struct colour { unsigned int R: 3; unsigned int G: 3; unsigned int B: 2; };`. I don't know of any system that ever existed that actually had 256 colours in this way though (VGA had a 256-colour palette but each of those colours was 18-bit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is a structure that can hold *three* values, each in the range `0..255`. Your proposed structure holds 3*256 * sizeof(int) = 768 * sizeof(int), way too much. Use this instead:

```
struct color {
    unsigned char R;
    unsigned char G;
    unsigned char B;
};
```

Note the correct placement of the struct identifier `color`.

You would use this structure further on in your program like this:

```
struct color bright_orange;

bright_orange.R = 255;
bright_orange.G = 128;
bright_orange.B = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

The array fields are unnecessary. A single `int` can hold values from 0 to 255 and is thus adequate for representing each of the shades. However, `uint8_t` is smaller and conveys the desired range of values explicitly:

```
#include <stdint.h> //Contains uint8_t
typedef struct color {
    uint8_t R;
    uint8_t G;
    uint8_t B;
} color_t;

color_t very_red;
very_red.R = 255U;
very_red.G = 0U;
very_red.B = 0U;
```

Note how `typedef` lets you subsequently reference `color_t` rather than having to write `struct color`.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong. Remove the array and you move color right after struct. You try (with wrong syntax) to create a color struct with R,G and B arrays of size 256 (256 int values each).
struct Color{
int R,
int G,
int B
};

By the way: You only need 8bits to address 256 states of R,G,B. So uint8_t (unsigned char) will be a better candidate in comparison to int.

Answer (score 0):

One `int` is 4 bytes so with 3 `int` you take 12 bytes.

If you use 3 `unsigned char` (which take only 1 byte each) you can save 75% of space (if we don't count the eventual padding).

And there is no need for array here.

Also this statement is false: "can represent 256 different colors" it's 256 * 256 * 256 colors...